# Как определить род связующего местоимения?

Tags: члены-предложения

Дан текст:
*Часть потолка представляла собой стеклянный купол — лантерну. Я открывала (его/её?), когда поднималась наверх.*
Купол — м.р.
Лантерна — ж.р.
Какое местоимение выбрать?

Answer (score 3):

По-моему, на выбор автора, ошибки не будет.

*Часть потолка представляла собой стеклянный купол - лантерну. Я открывала его, когда поднималась наверх.* Понятно, что открывала купол.

*Часть потолка представляла собой стеклянный купол - лантерну. Я открывала её, когда поднималась наверх.* Понятно, что открывала лантерну, часть потолка.

Однако лучше таких конструкций не допускать и перестроить фразу, уточнив, что именно открывала, может быть с помощью ещё одного названия, например: *Я открывала  эту удивительную дверцу на крышу, когда поднималась наверх* или с помощью повтора.

Answer (score 1):

В Ваше предложение, как мне кажется, вкралась "архитектурная" ошибка.

[**Латерна (лантерна)**](https://architect.academic.ru/3310/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0) в архитектурном словаре:
1. Возведенная над световым отверстием в крыше или куполе круглая, овальная или многогранная башенка с остеклением окон, превышающим по площади простенки.
2. (франц. *lanterne* - фонарь) — **башенка на куполе**, световой фонарик, служащий завершением купола.

*Грациозное здание увенчано плоским **куполом с изящной башенкой-лантерной…**

Старейшие сооружения замка – главная пятиугольная башня (1326-1327), увенчанная в 1714 году восьмиугольным барочным **куполом с лантерной…***

Предложение может быть таким:
**Часть потолка представляла собой купол со стеклянной башенкой – лантерной.**
Тогда возникает вопрос: что же Вы тогда открывали?

Answer (score 0):

**Лантерна** — (итал. lanterna — "фонарь"). Небольшая башенка на верхушке купола, проёмы которой являются источником верхнего света.

Если слово употреблено и указано его значение, то лучше использовать его:

**Часть потолка представляла собой стеклянный купол — лантерну. Я открывала её, когда поднималась наверх.**

Answer (score 0):

Для полной ясности я предпочёл бы назвать открываемое явно: "**Эту лантерну** я открывала..." Иначе по невнимательности при женском роде можно подумать на "*часть потолка*" (особенно если введённый термин с окончанием -у воспринять несклоняемым), а при мужском - на "*купол*" (термин для которого зачем-то привела) и даже на "*потолок*" (это было целью, а средства я на всякий случай уточнила).